# How can I divide a Perl array into smaller arrays?

Tags: php, perl, arrays

Is there any Perl equivalent for [php's array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)?

I'm trying to divide a large array into several smaller ones.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[splice()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) function.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. Moving from php to perl is not an easy job :)

Comment: @Antonio: Not an easy job, but it really worth it ! :)

Comment: Why is it not an easy job?

Comment: Examine List::MoreUtils for their implementation of n-at-a-time (natatime) function which uses splice and an anonymous function

Answer (score 8):

You can use array slices like this:

```
#!/bin/perl -l

my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

print join ",", @array[0..2];
print join ",", @array[3..5];
print join ",", @array[6..$#array];
```

Answer (score 3):

To match the PHP function you can use a number of approaches:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime part );

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = 0..9;
my $size = 3;

{    my $i = 0;
     my @part = part { int( $i++ / $size ) } @array;
     warn "PART\n";
     warn Dumper \@part;
}

{    my $iter = natatime( $size, @array );
     my @natatime;
     while( my @chunk = $iter->() ) {
        push @natatime, \@chunk;
     }
     warn "NATATIME\n";
     warn Dumper \@natatime;
}

{    my @manual;
     my $i = 0;

     for( 0..$#array ) {
         my $row = int( $_ / $size );

         $manual[$row] = [] 
             unless exists $manual[$row];

         push @{$manual[$row]}, $array[$_];
     }

     warn "MANUAL:\n";
     warn Dumper \@manual;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the easier ways is to use [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) and either the [`natatime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils#natatime) or [`part`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils#part) functions.

With natatime, it creates an iterator, so this might not be what you want:

```
my $iter = natatime 3, @orig_list;
```

And every call to `$iter->()` returns 3 items in the list.

Then there's `part`.

```
my $i      = 0;
my @groups = part { int( $i++ / 3 ) } @orig_array;
```

If you want to make this easier, you can write your own function: `chunk_array`.

```
sub chunk_array { 
    my $size = shift;
    my $i    = 0;
    return part { int( $i++ / $size ) } @_;
}
```

And you would call it as simple as:

```
my @trios = chunk_array( 3, @orig_array );
```